# Нужно ли тире в предложении "Впереди (?) проведение торжественного концерта"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Предложение:

> Впереди проведение торжественного концерта.

Необходимо ли в нем тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире по основному правилу не требуется, но можно поставить интонационное тире:

***Впереди — проведение торжественного концерта.***

См. примеры: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2%EF%E5%F0%E5%E4%E8&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=bdash&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=

Ср.:

***[Впереди](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ZWYKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22&dq=%22%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ48ny7tbgAhVYAhAIHSalCHUQ6AEILjAB) — проведение научных экспериментов, расстыковка и новая стыковка, в которой активную роль будет исполнять корабль «Союз».***

Answer (score 2):

Возможны два варианта:

***Впереди — проведение торжественного концерта.***

***Впереди проведение торжественного концерта.***

Тире интонационное, его постановка (при наличии паузы) зависит от контекста. Например, тире **можно не ставить** в сложном предложении: *Теперь все приготовления закончены, впереди проведение торжественного концерта*. (В таком предложении пауза  факультативна).

А если это самостоятельное предложение, то тире лучше поставить.

**Пояснение**

Это эллиптическое предложение вида "обстоятельство — подлежащее".

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

1. **Тире ставится при наличии паузы** в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым): За калиткой — третий плац, строевой, необыкновенной величины (Купр.)

**При отсутствии паузы тире** в эллиптическом предложении не ставится: А в доме стук, ходьба… (Гр.); Вдруг передо мною рытвина глубокая (Л.);

Answer (score 0):

Нет, тире не нужно. Правильно:

> Впереди проведение торжественного концерта.

Дело в том, что тире между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится по определенным правилам, узнать о которых можно, например, [здесь](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172). Рассматриваемый нами случай под эти правила не подпадает.